# Knockout select binding cannot get selectedOptions to work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In my markup I have a simple `<select>` tag hat I've bound with Knockout JS, like so:

```
<select data-bind="options: CountriesOptions, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', selectedOptions: SelectedCountries" multiple></select>
```

My view-model looks like this (*simplified*)

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> CountriesOptions { get; set; }

    public int[] SelectedCountries { get; set; }    
}
```

And in my controller I'm populating the model like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var model = new CountryViewModel();
        model.CountriesOptions = db.Countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "" + c.CountryId,
                Text: c.Name
            });

        model.SelectedCountries = new int[]{1, 2, 3}

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This example is very simplified but it does the job.

**Problem**

Whenever I load page and the binding is done, the `<select>` is filled with all the countries, which is the way I want it, but the `selectedOptions` is not working. Nothing is selected at all, thought my array looks exactly like `int[]{1, 2, 3}`. I'm not quite sure why this isn't working.

**EDIT**

**JS scribbles**

```
@using (Html.BeginScripts())
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jqueryui-datepicker")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Create ViewModel
        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(jsonData));
        vm.loading = ko.observable(false);

        // Init validation
        ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: true, parseInputAttributes: true, messagesOnModified: true });
        vm.errors = ko.validation.group(vm, { deep: true, observable: true, live: true });

        ko.applyBindings(vm);

    </script>

}
```

**EDIT**

I just found yet another issue with this binding. If I choose 2 countries from the select, they are NOT returned as selected. Bear in mind that this is `SelectListItem`'s so they have a property called `Selected`

I'm trying to get all selected items when they return to the controller (*when the user presses submit*):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var selectedCountries = model.Countriesoptions.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
}
```

But `selectedCountries` is an empty list.

Comment: Can you share the JS code also, pls ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ added

Comment: Did you try to define the ViewModel (`vm`) "manually" (to ensure arrays are `observableArray`) ? (even if `ko.mapping.fromJS` should do the job)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you miss the `multiple` attribute on your `select`. With it, things work as expected. Here's a demo with your code, with that attribute added and missing bits of code stubbed:

```js
var data = {
  CountriesOptions: [
    { Text: "USA", Value: 1 },
    { Text: "Greenland", Value: 4 },
    { Text: "Canada", Value: 3 },
    { Text: "Mexico", Value: 2 }
  ],
  SelectedCountries: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}

// Create ViewModel
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
vm.loading = ko.observable(false);

// Init validation
ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: true, parseInputAttributes: true, messagesOnModified: true });
vm.errors = ko.validation.group(vm, { deep: true, observable: true, live: true });

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: CountriesOptions, 
                   optionsText: 'Text', 
                   optionsValue: 'Value',
                   selectedOptions: SelectedCountries"
         multiple>
</select>
<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: I forgot to put the `multiple` attribute in the samples I've showed you. I already have the attribute in my own project, and this doesn't do any difference.

Comment: Then please review the differences between my example and the question code, because I fear the root cause might be missing in the code you've shown. Try to first track down whether the problem is front- or back-end by isolating both parts from eachother (as e.g. I've done in my example for the front-end bit). Good luck!